# Seeking 32 bit board for embedded development

Tags: embedded, arm

Im seeking an board with uart for rs232 (db9) and usb communication. I am wanting to write serial communication code in C++. I would like and LCD and i2c compatibility and onboard embedded debugger via usb.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the USB port for serial communication as a virtual com port "VCP" instead of the traditional serial port, then the [discovery board](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF252419) may be a valid option. Also you can get expansions to the board from [here](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM146/CL1984/SC720/SS1462/PF255417?sc=stm32f4dis-expansion).